# Entity Framework Generated SQL - SELECT TOP (X) takes 500% more time that SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, select, telerik

I am developing an MVC website that uses the Entity Framework. I am an ex ADO.Net forms man, so it's all a bit new to me. My EDM currently consists of an abstract "Product" Entity, which has 5 different "type" Entities that inherit from it. The "Product" Entity maps to 7 or 8 tables and has about 50 properties, each "type" that inherits from a "Product" has some 5 to 20 extra properties that extend a "Product". I notice that when I used the .Take extension method on the IQueryable to return data to a Telerik grid, it was taking noticably longer to return data than if I just greedily returned the whole collection to memory using .ToList.

When I ran SQL Profiler to see just what the devil was going on, here is what I found.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (20)
[Project12].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project12].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project12].[C3] AS [C3], 
etc ... 508 SQL lines follow, too much to paste here unfortunately.
```

Takes 500 milliseconds to execute. The following however:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
[Project12].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project12].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project12].[C3] AS [C3], 
etc ...
```

Takes around 80 milliseconds to execute.

So, judging by the above logic, I should ditch deferred execution, and every time the user changes page... take the entire dataset down into memory (500 rows or so). Does anyone have any suggestions what is going on and why SQL Server 2005 is behaving in this way?

**EDIT**

I've placed the full SQL on http://pastebin.com/rAGGSScA . Could it be that SQL is caching the "full" select, and not caching the "TOP (20)" results?

*Client Statistics for SELECT*

[image: Select]

*Client Statistics for SELECT TOP (20)*

[image: Select Top]

Comment: Please post both execution plans. Also any `ORDER BY` on either or both?

Comment: Are the two queries *exactly* the same, except of `TOP (20)`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and yes, they are exactly the same other than the `TOP (20)`. I've pasted the full SQL on pastebin. I'll run the execution plans for both out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your "508 SQL lines [that] follow" will be an ORDER BY clause.  By forcing a "TOP (N)" evaluation on the query, you are forcing the server to evaluate for this order by clause much earlier and compute *all* of the results (including their order) before *any* can be shown.  You'll likely end up with an entirely different execution plan, and may even void an index (or match of up with a less-desirable index).  Without a "TOP (n)" clause, the server can begin showing results as soon as it knows a record will be used.

Comment: This only makes sense if the other query **doesn't** have an order by (which isn't stated in the question). Otherwise sort is still a blocking operator for both.

Comment: Adding an index that covers the columns in the ORDER BY clause (in the same order) should improve the query time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have posted a link to the full SQL in the edit above. I'll run out the execution plans and also run the SQL tuning adviser to see what that says. Check out what "C2" (that it is sorting by) actually is as far as the Entity Framework is concerned. Any suggestions? (my first reaction is to dump the SQL the Entity Framework generating and get more control with SPs)

Answer (score 1):

If they both have an `ORDER BY` then my guess is that the slow one is using a different plan that is less generally efficient but that outputs the rows in the desired sort order and the fast plan uses a different plan which outputs the rows in non sorted order and has an explicit `SORT` step.

It may be the case that when using the slower plan SQL Server needs to process many more than 20 rows in order to get the `TOP 20` for output (as many are eliminated by joins or where clause criteria) and it does not estimate this factor correctly leading it to incorrectly cost the slow plan as being cheaper than the fast one.